# Problem in cloning github private respository to C panel version control system (public key denied)

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am using VPS inmotion hosting. I tried to clone my public github repository and it works fine but when I try to clone private repository, it fails with error Permission denied (publickey).

I have generated ssh keys on my local system and copied that ssh into github "SSH and GPG keys" ssh panel.

Also I imported same ssh key into my cpanel SSH Access panel and authorised it.
I used mycpanelusername@mydomainname.com while creating ssh key with no password.
should I use my myemail@gmail.com?

In github there is also tab "Deploy key" under setting section in which we can also include ssh keys..

I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try cloning your repository using an HTTPS URL instead of an SSH one.
That way (after entering your credentials: GitHub user account/GitHub password), you will know if this works as expected.

Regarding SSH, you need to follow "[Adding a new SSH key to your GitHub account](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account)".

Comment: hello . can u provie an example for using https ; i have a public host and dont have ssh access

Comment: @hamiidrezaGholami That would be: `git clone https://github.com/<aUser>/<aRepo>`

Comment: ty for response @VonC but i dont see any password provided in your example .should it be like https://github.com/<aUser>/password/<aRepo ?

Comment: @hamiidrezaGholami No, Git will prompt for you to enter the password, if this is a provate repository. If it is a public repository, you don't need a password for cloning. Only for pushing back to it.